# Way to speed up numpy matrix multiplication for calculating gaussian probability densities

Tags: numpy, probability, matrix-multiplication

I want to calculate the probability density for a large number of vectors using the Gaussian normal distribution in higher dimension formula and right now I have this working-

```py
def f(self, x):
    #               [1x2]     [2x2]    [2x1] ==> [1x1]
    return np.exp(-(x.T @ self.inv_cov @ x) / 2) 

np.apply_along_axis(self.f, 1, x_m.T)
```

corresponding to the formula in the box here

[image]

Which if fine, but is very slow. Is there any other way better than `apply_along_axis` to get the same result?

I am looking for a method where `[nx2]x[2x2]x[2xn] = [nx1]` n can be varied.

---

I did find a workaround but it takes up whooping amount of memory and numpy just says it's not possible

The workaround is to just take diagonal elements of the resulting `[nxn]` matrix from this calculation `[nx2]x[2x2]x[2xn]`

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a speed tool.  What's your `x_m` shape?  2d?  SImple iteration is just as good.  But `@` does `batch` calculations, able to do   `[m x 1x2]     [m x 2x2]    [m x 2x1] ==> [m x 1x1]`.  `np.einsum` can also be used for that.

Comment: What's wrong with just `np.exp(-(x.T @ self.inv_cov @ x) / 2)`, no `apply_along_axis`?

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the information about **batch calculations** , I got it working. My x_m is [2xn] and np.einsum is something that I came across recently and have to look into it!

Comment: @QuangHoang calculating the exponential when x is matrix will lead to a matrix (the term within brackets), whereas what is needed is either a scalar or a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hpaulj comment earlier, I was able to make use of batch calculations as follows-

My x_m dimension is [2xN] and with this modification the calculation turns into the dimesnions as exactly @hpaulj had commented --> `[m x 1x2][m x 2x2][m x 2x1] ==> [m x 1x1]`

```py
np.exp(-np.reshape(x_m.T, (x_m.shape[1], 1, 2)) @ 
       np.repeat(np.expand_dims(self.inv_cov, axis=0), x_m.shape[1], axis=0) @ 
       np.reshape(x_m.T, (x_m.shape[1], 2, 1))/2)
```